# Adding Support for Multiple Language to a Web Page?

Tags: html, web

I know I could do this by simply copying the files over, changing the names (adding a language code like "about" versus "about_es", or "contact" versus "contact_es") and basically redirecting them to a different site altogether, but I was wondering how to go about doing this like the Elder Scrolls website does it (URL is the same). It seems like that method would be more elegant/professional.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just serving pure HTML files or are you working on a Java/.NET/PHP/Whatever backed system?

Answer (score 0):

you can create resource JSON or XML file

ex1:

```
<languages>
    <language id="EN">
        <element name="page_head" >Hello world</element>
        <element name="page_footer" >goodbye world</element>
    </language>

    <language id="FR">
        <element name="page_head">Bonjour tous le monde</element>
        <element name="page_footer">Heureux voir tous le monde</element>
    </language>
</languages>
```

ex2:

```
a=[{
"language":"EN",
"elements":
    {
    "page_head":"Hello world",
    "page_footer":"goodbye world"
    }
},
{
"language":"EN",
"elements":
    {
    "page_head":"Bonjour tous le monde",
    "page_footer":"Heureux voir tous le monde"
}];
```

or maybe you can just use a lazy way aka "databases"!